# Kronecker Product and state space

Tags: matrices, control-theory, kronecker-product

I am reading a paper, and one step of it seems like the following:

If $S_1 = $ [image]

Then, $I \otimes S_1$ = [image]

How to show it?  (Suppose dimension of all of them are correct. $I$ is the identity matrix.)

Is it possible to replace $I$ to other matrix with the same dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to rhe Wikipedia definition 
$$
I \otimes S = [\delta_{ij} S]
= 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
S & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & S & \cdots& 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 &\cdots & S 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$ 
which is not what you want to show.

Maybe the product is defined the other way round?
$$
I \, \hat{\otimes}\, S = S \otimes I = [s_{ij} I]
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
a_{ij} I & b_{ij} I \\
\hline
c_{ij} I & d_{ij} I \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A \otimes I & B \otimes I \\
\hline
C \otimes I & D \otimes I \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
I \,\hat{\otimes}\, A & I \,\hat{\otimes}\, B \\
\hline
I \,\hat{\otimes}\, C & I \,\hat{\otimes}\, D \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: But $I \otimes S$ is not equal to $S \otimes I$

Comment: That is the point. I assume your text uses $\hat{\otimes}$. Note the silly hats I added to distinguish the different products operators.

Comment: Could you say more about the third '=' ?

Comment: That is just the fact that the matrix $S$ is partitioned into four blocks. Each element gets a $I$ matrix  as factor. The block partitioning is kept.